# Definite integral of a function that doesn't have an antiderivative

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I tried all the methods I know to find $$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3+\cos(x)}}\, dx$$  and it turns out that this function doesn't have an antiderrivative so I can't find the definite integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Can you please help me with a way to find the value if this integral?

Comment: Which methods did you try?

Comment: I tried u sub(once with the square root and once with just the cos and once with 3+cos and once)and tried t=tg(x/2). And I also tried to use u=π-x and cenvert to x to get two forms of the same integral but non of them gave any simpler or workable results

Comment: Can you please show me how it's done? I'm not very flexible with the gamma function

Answer (score 1):

It has an antiderivative which cannnot express in terms of elementary functions.
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a+\cos(x)}}=\frac 2 {\sqrt{a+1}} \, F\left(\frac x 2 | \frac 2 {a+1} \right)$$ where appears an incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Now, for your definite integral $(a=3)$ this gives
$$F\left(\frac \pi 2 | \frac 1 {2} \right)=K\left( \frac 1 {2} \right)=\frac {8 \pi^{3/2}}{\left[\Gamma\left(-\frac1 4\right)\right]^2}$$